# GNU parallel is not processing all the files

Tags: linux, memory, java, gnu-parallel

I am using GNU parallel to process BAM files for marking duplicates using java-based picard tool. The reason of using parallel utility is that the picard tool is not multi-thread and the dataset is very huge. So I am using the following command with GNU parallel:

```
ls *.bam | sed 's/.bam.*//' | parallel --eta -j 12 "java -jar picard.jar MarkDuplicates I={}.bam O=/bam1/{}.bam M=/bam1/{}_dup_matrices.txt"
```

**Expectation**
Since my server has 40 threads and 126 GB RAM, I was hoping that the above command will process all the bam files present in the current directory while processing 12 bam at a time.

**Actual Output**
In the end, I am getting only 4 or 5 processed BAM files while the current directory has around 15 BAM files. I am also getting an error of memory overflow (although I have checked the memory allocation using command `ulimit` and it shows unlimited).

Is it possible to use GNU parallel utility such that it automatically process all the files present in the current directory without and memory issue?

EDIT-1: I am adding the output of `ulimit -a` here:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 514974
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 514974
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Post the output of `ulimit -a`.

Comment: @OleTange I have added the output of `ulimit -a` in the question as EDIT-1. Please check.

Comment: Does it process all if you use `parallel -j1`?

Comment: Yes. It is processing all the files from `parallel -j1` to `parallel -j4`. It shows error with `parallel -j8` also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java` often reserves a lot more memory than it uses. 10x is not uncommon. So if we assume that `picard` actually uses 3 GB, but reserves 30 GB then you can only run 4 jobs in parallel before you run out of memory - unless you add swapspace.

Just because `java` reserves the memory, it does not mean it ever touches it.

My suggestion is that you add 1 TB of swapspace.

You can also ask the Linux kernel to overcommit memory. But I have bad experience with unexpected crashes of the server when doing that, so I would recommend against that solution.

But you *can* use zswap. This way if anything would be written to swap, the kernel will first try to compress it and keep it in RAM. Only if it fails to do so, will the memory be written to disk. Combined with the 1 TB (slow) swap space on disk, this works quite efficient.